# Growing text box based on width of characters input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a text box that grows every time a letter is added to it by the width of the character. This is what I'm trying. It doesn't work. If you've got a hint, please share!

JavaScript:

```
function MakeWidth(el) {
        el.style.width = parseFloat(el.value.clientWidth) }
```

HTML:

```
<input id="Test" type="text" style="width: 10px;" onkeyup="MakeWidth(this)"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `size` & `length` instead of `clientWidth` & `width`

http://jsfiddle.net/eVd9b/5/

```
function MakeWidth(el) {
    el.size = parseInt(el.value.length);
}
```

which should be suitable for your needs.

Comment: Why do the first few characters get chopped off? Tried in Firefox.

Comment: I'm not sure, it works pretty fine in Chrome 15 and Opera. Try [monospace](http://jsfiddle.net/eVd9b/6/) font

Comment: After testing awhile, this method does not discern that 'W' and 'i' have different widths in non monospace fonts. I'm looking for a solution that does.

Comment: @Mike: That is really problematic. monospce font is your surety.

Answer (score 3):

It may be more useful to use the `size` attribute.

```
<input id="Test" type="text" size="1" onkeyup="MakeWidth(this)"/>
<script>
function MakeWidth(el) {
        el.size = el.value.length

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit tricky since you don't necessarily know the width of each character. One little trick that comes to mind is that you could try creating a hidden div with the typed character, grab it's width, add it to the textbox width and destroy the hidden div.